# Converting UNIX timestamp to date gives incorrect result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to convert a UNIX timestamp to a human-readable date in JavaScript, but I am getting unexpected results. The UNIX timestamp I have is 665346600, which should correspond to February 1, 2022.

I am using the following JavaScript code to perform the conversion:

```js
const timestampInSeconds = 665346600;
const timestampInMilliseconds = timestampInSeconds * 1000;

const date = new Date(timestampInMilliseconds);

console.log(date.toISOString());
```

However, the output I am getting is 1991-03-02T17:16:40.000Z, which is incorrect. I was expecting 2022-02-01T05:30:00.000Z.

I have double-checked the timestamp value and also tried various online timestamp conversion tools, all of which confirm that 665346600 corresponds to February 1, 2022.

Am I doing something wrong in my code, or is there a different approach I should be using to correctly convert this UNIX timestamp to the corresponding date?

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: timestamp `665346600` is GMT Thu Jan 31 1991 18:30:00, if I run your code in my browser I get `1991-01-31T18:30:00.000Z`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a date object from a timestamp it's created in UTC.

To fix that you should shift minutes with the timezone offset:

```js
const timestampInSeconds = 665346600;
const timestampInMilliseconds = timestampInSeconds * 1000;

const date = new Date(timestampInMilliseconds);

// fix the timezone offset
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());

console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Comment: Re "*When you create a date object from a timestamp it's created in UTC*". **All** *Dates* are (effectively) created as UTC, not just those using a numeric value. ;-)

Comment: @RobG except maybe `new Date('2023-07-19T15:56:17')`. that's why i've added the remark

Comment: The timestamp '2023-07-19T15:56:17' will be parsed to create a time value, which is an offset in milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC. The associated offset (in this case, the related local offset) is considered during the parse to create the time value. The time value is the only data value of a *Date* instance, hence all Dates can be considered as UTC.